# Improve FAQ description of cross-site rep bonus

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request, meta-faq

As a new user on StackOverflow, I found the FAQ's description of the +100 rep bonus for having over 200 rep on at least one site to be a little confusing. The way it is phrased, it's pretty clear that if I already have 200 reputation on one site, I will automatically get a bonus when I log in to another Stack Exchange site. But it is not at all clear what happens if I am **not** "an experienced Stack Exchange network user" and don't have 200 rep on any site at the time I create an account. Will I get that bonus on all my existing accounts as soon as I reach 200 rep on one of them? Or does it only work if I wait until I get 200 rep on at least one site before creating a new account at another Stack Exchange site?

I figured out the answer to these questions by trial and error: I avoided creating any other accounts on Stack Exchange until I had 200 rep on StackOverflow, but I was forced to create an account on DBA when one of my questions was migrated there. Then when I reached 200 rep, my DBA account automatically got a 100 rep bonus. (And as I expected, the new account I created on Meta after reaching 200 rep on SO started with 100 rep.) For the benefit of other new users, though, I think it would really help if the FAQ covered what happens to the rep bonus if you create a new linked account before you have 200 rep. In its current form, I think other users like myself will be discouraged from creating other SE accounts until they reach 200 rep on SO (which is not an easy thing to do if you're not an expert with an enormous breadth of knowledge).

Comment: No link to FAQ? .... and where to look within it?

Comment: I thought it would be easy enough to find the FAQ I was talking about, but here's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#login